# Time attendance system how to mach a user with a spesific shift taking into consideration entrance time? Laravel // PHP // Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, time

A time attendance system can have many shifts.

For instance:

Shift a) 08:00 - 16:00,

Shift b) 16:00 - 00:00,

Shift c) 00:00 - 08:00,

A user starts working at 07:55 what is the best way to match this user with the correct shift which is shift a?

Keep in mind that the time attendance system may have many shifts much closer together, for instance a
shift that starts at 8:00 and a shift that starts at 9:00.

Important info:
What i have done is a foreach loop that compares all starting times of the shifts (in our example 09:00, 16:00, 00:00) with the time that user started working. In our example 7:55.
The one that is closer to the users start working time is the correct shift.

This looks like its ok but in reality its not. The reason is that when time is round 00:00:00 and since times of shifts do not have a date, when the comparison is 23:59:59 and 00:00:01 i get 86400 secs instead of just 2 secs. 
Additional you never know which date is greater than the other, because a user may come earlier for work or late.
So any ideas must take these into consideration.

Thanks for efforts

Comment: > since times of shifts do not have a date
That sounds like your problem. Having a timestamp would simplify this and allow you to more accurately calculate the distance from a shift.

Comment: @James you are correct but how can i add dates in such a case?? Should i force weekly  shifts?? for instance for each day shifts???

Comment: I can't really comment on how you should architect this as I have no knowledge of your system. A shift should represent a specific time and date, e.g this shift is scheduled for this date and time. It sounds like you may need a shift template, or something similar, that allows the admin to setup what a typical week should look like and the shift template can then be used to generate the specific shifts for dates and matching times.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the answer based on the comment, but there is not enough information in the question to show you how to query your database and convert your shifts into the array I'm using in this example.

This codeblock is reference, not code to use. This is the array of start times you need to convert your database table to.

```
$shift_starts = [
    // 1 represents the ID of the shift in your database.    
    1 => [
        // Shift ID 1 starts at midnight, hour 0, minute 0
        [0, 0],
    ],
    // 2 represents the ID of the shift in your database.
    2 => [
        // Shift ID 2 starts at 8am, hour 8, minute 0
        [8, 0],
    ],
    // 3 represents the ID of the shift in your database.
    3 => [
        // Shift ID 3 starts at 4pm, hour 16, minute 0
        [16, 0],
    ],
];
```

Create a function, something like this. Again, I don't know how you are querying your database, nor the schema. I just know how you are storing the start times:

```
// Psudeo Code!!! Study and write your own function that returns
// the array as defined above.
function get_shift_start_array() {
    $shift_starts = [];
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM shifts ORDER BY start_time");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        // If the start_time is formatted h:m:s, then make it so you can get hours
        // and minutes into their own variables:
        $arr = explode(':', $row['start_time']);
        $hour = $arr[0];
        $minute = $arr[1];
        $shift_starts[$row->id] = [$hour, $minute];
    }
    return $shift_starts;
}
```

Now that we have a way to get your shift data into a format we can code around, this function will take a unix timestamp and return the database ID of the shift. (Notice this function calls the function above)

Read the comments and study the PHP functions you might not understand.

```
/**
 * Get the shift ID for a specific time.
 *
 * @param int $punchin_time Unix timestamp Default is the current time.
 * @return int The shift id (the array key from $shift_starts)
 */
function findShift($punchin_time = null): int
{
    if ($punchin_time === null) {
        $punchin_time = time();
    }

    // Call the psudo code function to get an array of shift start times keyed by shift id.
    $shift_starts = get_shift_start_array();

    // Set $day to the unix timestamp of midnight yesterday.
    $day = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', $punchin_time - 86400));
    // We'll be checking the difference between punchin time and the shift time.
    // $last_diff will be used to compare the diff of the current shift to the last shift.
    // Initialize this with an arbitrarily high value beyond the 3 days we're looking at.
    $last_diff = 86400 * 5; //
    $last_index = null;

    // Loop over 3 days starting with yesterday to accommodate punchin times before midnight.
    // Return the shift ID when we find the smallest difference between punchin time and shift start.
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        // Get the month, day, and year numbers for the day we are iterating on.
        // We will use these in our calls to mktime()
        $m = date('n', $day);
        $d = date('j', $day);
        $y = date('y', $day);

        // Loop over each shift.
        foreach ($shift_starts as $index => $start) {
            // Create a unix timestamp of the shift start time.
            // This is the date and time the shift starts based on the day iteration.
            $time = mktime($start[0], $start[1], 0, $m, $d, $y);

            // Get the difference in seconds between this shift start time and the punchin time.
            $diff = abs($punchin_time - $time);

            // $diff should be getting smaller as we get closer to the actual shift.
            if ($diff > $last_diff) {
                // If $diff got bigger than the last one, we've past the shift.
                // Return the index of the last shift.
                return $last_index;
            }
            $last_index = $index;
            $last_diff = $diff;
        }
        $day = strtotime('+1 day', $day);
    }
    // Return null if no shift found.
    return null;
}
```

Now that the functions are defined, you just need to call the last one to convert specific time, to a shift.

```
$punchin_time = mktime(15, 55, 0, 4, 15, 2020);
$shift_id = findShift($punchin_time);
```

Alternatively, don't pass a time in and the current time will be used.

```
$shift_id = findShift($punchin_time);
```

[mktime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)
[strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
[DateTime::getTimestamp()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)

Comment: In case you referenced the code before now, I just fixed a couple things.

Comment: Hi @Coder1. 
First of all thank you for your effort! 
Secondly i think i do like the way you approached this but i am not sure i understood 100% your  code.

$punchin_time is not known because we dont know when the user is coming. So it  should be a variable something like 

$punchin_time = Carbon::now(); // The time the user came in for work.

$shift_starts are the shifts that the admin added to the system (again not known) so we have to ask the DB.
$shift_starts = Shift::all();
Now in my shifts table i have 3 columns start, stop, and shiftduration.
Could you please readapt code?

Comment: Keep in mind that start and stop are times only in my DB. 
Like start = 21:10:00

Comment: @larabarb that's not really how it works here. The answers should match the question, and questions shouldn't be rewritten after someone takes the time to answer. I'd suggest studying the code, especially the `mktime()` function, then ask more specific questions after you have tried it. Include details with details on what you have tried. I'll revise this info a method that might make it slightly easier to use but I'd still be making too many assumptions to write code that you can copy and paste.

Comment: @larabarb The answer has been updated. If this approach seems like it might work but is still not making sense, I'd recommend studying the time functions and how unix timestamps work before crafting new question with more detail and code examples of what you're trying so anyone helping can answer in a way that applies closer to what you're working on. For example, include code examples of how you are querying for shifts. Good luck!